# Redis error: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis, node.js-connect

When I checked my redis-server status , it says redis server is running but I got this error when I log
RedisClient.on('error', function(err) {
console.log('Redis error: ' + err);// Redis error: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
});
and when I try to console the req.session it returns undefined. any clue about this issue?
please help me I am new to this. thank you

heres my setup:

```js
var express = require('express');
var redis = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var parser = require('body-parser');
var RedisClient= redis.createClient();

app.use(session({
secret: 'myseceret',
store: new redisStore({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379, client: client,ttl : 260}),
saveUninitialized: false,
resave: false,
cookie: { secure: true }
}));
client.on('error', function(err) {
console.log('Redis error: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided mutually exclusive parameters together in options for redisStore. You either pass the host and port or just existing redis client.

Quoting [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) docs -

> A Redis client is required. An existing client can be passed directly using the client param or created for you using the host, port, or socket params

Also there were some reference errors which I have corrected in this snippet.

```
var express = require('express');
var redis = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var parser = require('body-parser');
var RedisClient= redis.createClient();

var app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    store: new redisStore({client: RedisClient,ttl : 260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));

RedisClient.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Redis error: ' + err);
});

RedisClient.on("ready",function () {
    console.log("Redis is ready");
});
```

Comment: hi thank you. I've tried the code you provide and still got the same issue :(

Comment: when I check redis server by redis-cli ping. it says:
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused

Comment: Hi @fyeah , can you tell me your os environment, so I can help you further

Comment: I was trying to setup redis in my live production server using ubuntu 16.
its really my first time to set things up.please help me

Comment: Check whether redis server is running by using this command `sudo service redis status`. If it says stopped, start it by `sudo service redis start` else check the redis configuration file to check on which port it is running.

Comment: hey, I tried the command sudo service redis status and give me this response: 

sudo: unable to resolve host api

Comment: ● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-serve
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-02-17 0
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,

Comment: man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 1143 ExecStartPost=/bin/run-parts --ver
  Process: 1138 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /e
  Process: 1075 ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts --verb
 Main PID: 1140 (redis-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─1140 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:

Feb 17 02:53:36 api systemd[1]: Starting Advanced
Feb 17 02:53:36 api run-parts[1075]: run-parts: ex
Feb 17 02:53:36 api run-parts[1143]: run-parts: ex
Feb 17 02:53:36 api systemd[1]: Started Advanced k
lines 1-16/16 (

Comment: hi, I restarted my server and rerun sudo service redis start, I think I am not connected with redis (its weird bec I din't do anything) and seems like everything went fine bec I dont get  Connection refused err.

Comment: and when I run redis-cli its says : 
127.0.0.1:6379>

am I on the right track?

Comment: @fyeah , so are you saying you are not getting any further  Connection refused error?

Comment: yep i don't. Redis is ready is now logging. but one more thing, I use passport for authentication.
authentication went well, but it seem doesn't store data on req.session

Comment: @fyeah sorry I dont have much expertise in passportJS. Why dont you ask this as a separate question? You may be able to get relevant answers from passport JS community.

Comment: alright thank you @TabishRizvi much help. thank you so much